# Default values for constructor arguments in a library project

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, default-value, service-locator

I am writing a library that will provide a collection of public types to its consumers.

I want to make types from this library dependency injection friendly. This means that every class needs to have a constructor through which it is possible to specify every single dependency of the object being initialized. I also want the library to adhere to the convention over configuration principle. This means that if a consumer wants the default behavior, he may use a parameterless constructor and the object will somehow construct the dependencies for itself.

In example (C#):

```
public class Samurai {

    private readonly IWeapon _weapon;

    // consumers will use this constructor most of the time
    public Samurai() {
        _weapon = ??? // get an instance of the default weapon somehow
    }

    // consumers will use this constructor if they want to explicitly
    //   configure dependencies for this instance
    public Samurai(IWeapon weapon) {
        _weapon = weapon;
    }
}
```

My first solution would be to use the service locator pattern.

The code would look like this:

```
...
public Samurai() {
    _weapon = ServiceLocator.Instance.Get<IWeapon>();
}
...
```

I have a problem with this, though. Service locator has been flagged as an anti-pattern ([link](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx)) and I completely agree with these arguments. On the other hand, Martin Fowler advocates use of the service locator pattern exactly in this situation (library projects) ([link](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#DecidingWhichOptionToUse)). I want to be careful and eliminate the possible necessity to rewrite the library after it shows up that service locator really was a bad idea.

So in conclusion - do you think that service locator is fine in this scenario? Should I solve my problem in a completely different way? Any thought is welcome...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make life easier for users who are not using a DI container, you can provide default instances via a dedicated `Defaults` class which has methods like this:

```
public virtual Samurai CreateDefaultSamurai()
{
   return new Samurai(CreateDefaultWeapon());
}

public virtual IWeapon CreateDefaultWeapon()
{
   return new Shuriken();
}
```

This way you don't need to pollute the classes themselves with default constructors, and your users aren't at risk of using those default constructors unintentionally.

Comment: It's important to keep a class DI friendly. +1

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative, that is injecting a specific provider, let's say a `WeaponProvider` in your case into your class so it can do the lookup for you:

```
public interface IWeaponProvider
{
    IWeapon GetWeapon();
}

public class Samurai
{
    private readonly IWeapon _weapon;

    public Samurai(IWeaponProvider provider)
    {
        _weapon = provider.GetWeapon();
    }
}
```

Now you can provide a local default provider for a weapon:

```
public class DefaultWeaponProvider : IWeaponProvider
{
    public IWeapon GetWeapon()
    {
        return new Sword();
    }
}
```

And since this is a local default (as opposed to one from a different assembly, so it's not a "bastard injection"), you can use it as part of your Samurai class as well:

```
public class Samurai
{
    private readonly IWeapon _weapon;

    public Samurai() : this(new DefaultWeaponProvider())
    {
    }

    public Samurai(IWeaponProvider provider)
    {
        _weapon = provider.GetWeapon();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a really elegant alternative. I would just like to ask one more additional question.

Comment: Now I have to hardcode the binding of IWeaponProvider to DefaultWeaponProvider in the constructor of the Samurai class. Do you see a way how this binding could be refactored out to some composition module? Like with IOC containers you have a single configuration file where you define something like this "Bind<IWeaponProvider>().To<DefaultWeaponProvider>();" (- example from Ninject). Even if there is no way to do it, I will accept your answer. Just wanted to clarify...Thanks

Comment: just to clarify: by "convention over configuration" you mean you *still* want to configure what these default values are going to be? But yes, you could implement your `DefaultWeaponProvider` to bind its `IWeapon` to anything really, i.e. based on a config file or an internal use of an IoC container - but your `Samurai` class will not have any of those dependencies

Comment: I want to be able to configure the default values from one place, because I feel it is one coherent part of the application. But I want to do it inside of the library. A consumer of the library must not know about the fact, that there is some management of default values going on (map of interface-to-implementation bindings). At least he must not be required to explicitly define default values by himself. I think @wim-coenen's solution is fine because it enables me to manage default values from one place and user is not required to do configuration of any kind - if he does not want to do so.

Comment: I feel I should apologize, because I start to feel that this question has been vaguely specified and may not have a single correct answer. It could even become a discussion, which is not OK on SO and I know it. At this time hovewer, I think that @wim-coenen 's answer is more fitting to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following approach in my C# project. The goal was to achieve dependency injection (for unit / mock testing) whilst not crippling the implementation of the code for a "normal use case" (i.e. having a large amount of new()'s that are cascaded through the execution flow).

```
public sealed class QueueProcessor : IQueueProcessor
{
    private IVbfInventory vbfInventory;
    private IVbfRetryList vbfRetryList;

    public QueueProcessor(IVbfInventory vbfInventory = null, IVbfRetryList vbfRetryList = null)
    {
        this.vbfInventory = vbfInventory ?? new VbfInventory();
        this.vbfRetryList = vbfRetryList ?? new VbfRetryList();
    }
}
```

This allows DI but also means any consumer doesn't have to worry about what the "default instance flow" should be.